# Relation check in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have noticed one thing in hyperledger composer, after relating two entities, even if in input we give the id which is not existing it will accept the entry without checking whether the related asset or participant exists or not. Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bug, its by design.

this question is best answered by the comments shown here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3065#issuecomment-354953014

Hyperledger Composer doesn't enforce relationships (or those since 'disconnected' / 'orphaned' out on the ledger) - to try and preserve integrity of relationships would be a near impossible task (CouchDB is a key/value DB, not a relational DB :-) )

So its perfectly feasible to have an asset with an owner field, that's a relationship field in the asset, still referencing a participant record/instance that no longer exists. It is up to the application or client to enforce any 'referential integrity' checks, if that is so desired.